# How to mount/umount disk in console to get the same result as nautilus?

Tags: shell, nautilus

In `nautilus`, a disk can be mounted by mouse click, the results are

- **format**(NTFS) is recognized correctly
- **read/write** are permitted by non-root user

You can also umount a disk without root **permission** in nautilus.

How to simulate these mount/umount operations in `nautilus` with shell commands?

Comment: This exact question was asked [three years back](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483460/how-to-mount-from-command-line-like-the-nautilus-does) on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Nautilus uses `gvfs` to mount those locations. From the command line:

```
gvfs-mount smb://server/share mountpoint
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to *jordan* for pointing out that nautilus uses gvfs

```
Usage:
  gvfs-mount [OPTION...] [LOCATION...]

Mount the locations.

Help Options:
  -h, --help                      Show help options

Application Options:
  -m, --mountable                 Mount as mountable
  -d, --device=DEVICE             Mount volume with device file
  -u, --unmount                   Unmount
  -e, --eject                     Eject
  -s, --unmount-scheme=SCHEME     Unmount all mounts with the given scheme
  -f, --force                     Ignore outstanding file operations when unmounting or ejecting
  -a, --anonymous                 Use an anonymous user when authenticating
  -l, --list                      List
  -o, --monitor                   Monitor events
  -i, --detail                    Show extra information
  --version                       Show program version
```

Find mounted devices and their mount points:

```
gvfs-mount -l -i
```

Look for:

```
...
unix-device: '/dev/sdc1'
...
Mount(0): USBNAME -> file:///run/media/username/USBNAME
```

**Unmount the device:**

```
gvfs-mount -u -i /run/media/username/USBNAME
```

**Mount the device:**

```
gvfs-mount -d /dev/sdc1
```

Comment: What about mounting?

Comment: To mount a device: gvfs-mount -d /dev/sdc1

Answer (score 0):

You can use pmount, an application that allows normal users to mount removable devices:

```
pmount /dev/sda2 mydevice
```

Answer (score 0):

I belive Nautilus uses udisks for things like removable media:

```
udisks --mount /dev/sdc1
```

Use `man udisks` for several other commands.